# when running hexo migrate rss, it prompt: undefined migrator plugin is not installed

Tags: npm, hexo

After running of `npm install hexo-migrator-rss --save`.
I go to my blog file and open git bash, run`hexo migrate rss`, it prompt:

```
undefined migrator plugin is not installed.

Installed migrator plugins:

For more help, you can check the online docs: http://hexo.io/
```

How can I solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure, that you installed `hexo-migrate-rss` package in the right folder. Check that the package is listed in your `blog/package.json` :

**E.g** :

```js
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "hexo": {
    "version": "3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hexo": "3.1.1",
    "hexo-deployer-git": "0.0.4",
    "hexo-deployer-heroku": "0.0.3",
    "hexo-generator-archive": "^0.1.0",
    "hexo-generator-category": "^0.1.0",
    "hexo-generator-feed": "^1.0.1",
    "hexo-generator-index": "0.1.2",
    "hexo-generator-tag": "^0.1.0",
    "hexo-migrator-rss": "^0.1.2",
    "hexo-renderer-ejs": "^0.1.0",
    "hexo-renderer-marked": "^0.2.4",
    "hexo-renderer-stylus": "^0.2.0",
    "hexo-server": "^0.1.2",
    "hexo-util": "^0.1.6",
  }
}
```

It's important that `hexo-migrator-rss` is listed in `dependencies`, otherwise it will output that there is no migrator. That why, if you run `hexo-migrate-rss` without the `--save` arguments, Hexo won't find it.

Comment: Yeah!Forget to excute `$hexo-migrate-rss --save` and `$ npm install hexo-generator-feed --save` cause the problem.But what `--save` means?

Comment: `--save` will save the module and its version in `dependencies` in your `package.json`